# problem with calling imshow() of mathplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I am not sure if I am missing anything with mathplotlib imshow().

Following is the sample code I have written. I am a beginner to python.

```
I = pd.read_csv("D:\\Temp\\train.csv", header=None)
M = I.as_matrix()
im = M[1,1:]
im = im.reshape(28,28)
plt.imshow(im)
```

I am getting the following error.

need help on how to fix and better way to do this.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-277-628dc6c46325> in <module>()
      3 im = M[1,1:]
      4 im = im.reshape(28,28)
----> 5 plt.imshow(im)

C:\Users\mapppppp\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in imshow(X, cmap, norm, aspect, interpolation, alpha, vmin, vmax, origin, extent, shape, filternorm, filterrad, imlim, resample, url, hold, data, **kwargs)
   3156                         filternorm=filternorm, filterrad=filterrad,
   3157                         imlim=imlim, resample=resample, url=url, data=data,
-> 3158                         **kwargs)
   3159     finally:
   3160         ax._hold = washold

C:\Users\mapppppp\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1890                     warnings.warn(msg % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1891                                   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1892             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1893         pre_doc = inner.__doc__
   1894         if pre_doc is None:

C:\Users\mapppppp\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in imshow(self, X, cmap, norm, aspect, interpolation, alpha, vmin, vmax, origin, extent, shape, filternorm, filterrad, imlim, resample, url, **kwargs)
   5116                               resample=resample, **kwargs)
   5117 
-> 5118         im.set_data(X)
   5119         im.set_alpha(alpha)
   5120         if im.get_clip_path() is None:

C:\Users\mapppppp\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py in set_data(self, A)
    543         if (self._A.dtype != np.uint8 and
    544                 not np.can_cast(self._A.dtype, np.float)):
--> 545             raise TypeError("Image data can not convert to float")
    546 
    547         if (self._A.ndim not in (2, 3) or

TypeError: Image data can not convert to float
```

Comment: What does your matrix look like?

Comment: train.csv file I took it from https://www.kaggle.com/c/digit-recognizer.

Comment: Matrix is having the value between 0 to 255.